# How to disable a selected dropdown list item from the rest of the dropdowns, for a given group of dropdown fields, in html & Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I have a group of 6 drop down fields. Each field has select options 1 up to 6, what I want is if a user selects for example, 1 on the first drop down field, that option 1 gets disabled in the rest of the remaining 5 fields (we are collecting data from users on a scale of 1 to 6). Basically any given drop down option can only be selected once in the 6 fields. How can I achieve this in HTML and JavaScript? I just need pointers on how to get started.

**UPDATE:**

So this solution worked for my 6 questions, now we have 10 sets of 6 questions each, I have assigned a unique class to each of the 10 divs so I can be able to loop through all 10 sets and implement this functionality. I am now working on a solution to implement that, if anyone has pointers - they would be greatly appreciated, otherwise I will update the solution if I get it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could attach an event listener to the select tags, in order to disable the options of the other ones; for example:

```js
const selectList = document.getElementsByTagName("select")

for (let i = 0; i < selectList.length; i++) {
    selectList[i].addEventListener('change', (event) => disabler(event))
}

function reset() {
    for (let i = 0; i < selectList.length; i++) {
    for (let k = 0; k < selectList[i].length; k++) {
      selectList[i][k].disabled = false;
    }
  }
}

function disabler(event) {

  reset();

    for (let i = 0; i < selectList.length; i++) {

    selectedValue = selectList[i].value;

    for (let j = 0; j < selectList.length; j++) {

      for (let k = 0; k < selectList[j].length; k++) {
        if (selectList[j][k].value === selectedValue) {
          selectList[j][k].disabled = true;    
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

function submitValue() {
  const values = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < selectList.length; i++) {
      values.push(Number(selectList[i].value));
  }
  
  console.log(values)
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
</select> 
<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
</select> 
<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
</select> 
<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
</select> 
<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
</select> 
<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
</select>  
<input type="button" value ="Submit" onclick="submitValue()"></button>
</form>
```

this has a bug since you cannot move the values, but works as a POC.

Comment: I am having an issue. My form is seeing all these drop-downs as blank when I try to submit. I am still trying to figure out why.Any clues?

Comment: maybe share your code in pastebin, my example (i have updated it with a log of the values) works correctly

Comment: I see,I am using this on formidable forms wordpress plugin. Maybe its validation JS is clashing with my JS